# How to work params using props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, react-props, react-proptypes

I am new developer **ReactJS**, I develop a table with **ReactJS** on the FrontEnd, **NodeJS** on BackEnd and **MySQL** about the database.

I want when I click on the view button on Action column as below:
[image]

**My router :**

```
exports.viewclient = function(req, res) {
  var Code = req.query.Code;
    console.log(req.params);

    connection.query('SELECT Code, Prenom, Nom, FAX, Telephone, Email, Adresse1, Adresse2  FROM clients  WHERE Code = ?',[req.params.Code],  function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
console.log(results);
    });

}
```

**My server :**

r`outer.get('/viewclient/:Code', clients.viewclient);`

My **handleView** method on the class Liste :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clients: [],
      Code: this.props.match.params.Code


    };
handleView(Code) {
    try {

      console.log("Voir client")
      this.props.history.push('/clients/viewclient/' + Code);

    }
    catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  }
```

**View Class :**

```
 constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                clients: [],
                Code: this.props.match.params.Code


            };
console.log(this.props);
     componentDidMount() {


        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/' + this.state.Code)

            .then(response => {
                if (response && response.data) {
                    this.setState({ clients: response.data });
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

When I run the backend with Postman `http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/1111` it returns

```
[{"Code":1111,"Prenom":"test","Nom":"test","FAX":"58985688888","Telephone":"58985699888","Email":"test@gmail.com","Adresse1":"","Adresse2":""}]
```

But when I run my frontend, it redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/app/viewclient/undefined` and I can't view the result of Select.

The result of console.log(this.props) is :

[image]
How can I fix that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do one of 2 things to solve your issue.

1. Instead of using `this.state.code`, why not simply use `this.props.match.params.Code` in your axios request?
2. The reason why it's undefined, is because in the constructor you receive `props`, not `this.props`,
   so you should only really need to change it to the following.

`Code: props.match.params.Code`

Comment: Thanks @Chaim , I edit `Code: props.match.params.Code` on `class View` , it works well, can you up the post please ?